# Set CheckBox size to Box Size

Tags: checkbox, win-universal-app

How to set the `CheckBox` size to its box size?

I have a `CheckBox`. I need to set the size of checkbox to its box size. Now My checkbox looks as follows.

[image]

I set checkbox background to Transparent. When the background of parent is white, it is OK. But when the background of parent control is black The checkbox is invisible. So I need to set background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve but if you want to alter the layout of the checkbox, the easiest way is to create your own style.

Using Visual Studio, you can perform a right click on your checkbox from the "document outline" panel and select "edit template" > "edit copy".
This will allow you to duplicate the checkbox style and adjust it to what you need.

[image: Document outline panel]

Here is a sample of the CheckBox style:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,5,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="32"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Grid BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                [...]
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="NormalRectangle" Fill="Transparent" Height="20" Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeThickness}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="20"/>
                    <FontIcon x:Name="CheckGlyph" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Glyph="&#xE001;" Opacity="0"/>
                </Grid>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```